# Как в WPF не вручную создать колонки для ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть сотрудники, у них много полей - LastName, FirstName и т.д. Хочу отобразить список всех сотрудников в виде таблицы. Дело происходит в Wpf с MVVM паттерном. Так что у меня есть View с таким фрагментом:

```xml
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllEmployees}"
    >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Фамилия"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
                />
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Имя"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"
                />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Соответственно, есть ViewModel, в которой AllEmployees - это коллекция с объектами сотрудников. Эти объекты как раз имеют свойства LastName, FirstName и т.д.

Что я хочу? Не объявлять каждый GridViewColumn руками и не задавать ему Header и биндинг, а объявить во ViewModel какой-нибудь словарь (или еще как-нибудь, я просто привел пример) вроде такого

```cs
public Dictionary<string, string> Columns = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "EmployeeId", "Табельный №" },
    { "TitleOfCourtesy", "Обращение" },
    { "LastName", "Фамилия" },
    { "FirstName", "Имя" },
    { "Title", "Должность" },
    { "HireDate", "Дата найма" },
    { "ReportsTo", "Подчиняется" }
};
```

и формировать GridViewColumn'ы из этого словаря. Соответственно, по ключу было бы понятно, какое свойство брать из объекта сотрудника, а по значению - какой заголовок давать для этого свойства в таблице.

Не могу понять, как это оформить через XAML. То ли через шаблон колумна как-то, то ли еще как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобное поведение можно реализовать при помощи `AttachedProperty`.

- Создаем статичный класс, назовем его допустим `GridViewColumns`.
- В этом классе создаем три `AttachedProperty` (в студии есть сниппет для этого - `propa`):

  - Первый назовем `Source` (`object`) - будет служить для указания коллекции с колонками.
  - Второй будет `Header` (`string`) - отвечать будет за заголовок.
  - Ну и последний, `DisplayMember` (`string`) - отвечает за название свойства, которое данная колонка должна вывести.

  Получаем в итоге нечто такое:

  ```
  public static object GetSource(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(SourceProperty);
  public static void SetSource(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(object), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(default));

  public static string GetHeader(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderProperty);
  public static void SetHeader(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Header", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(default));

  public static string GetDisplayMember(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberProperty);
  public static void SetDisplayMember(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberProperty, value);
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(default));
  ```
- Теперь давайте подпишемся на обновление `Source` и в обработчике этого события создадим тестовые колонки:

  - Дописываем в регистрации у `Source` нужный нам обработчик

    ```
    new UIPropertyMetadata(default, SourceChanged)
    ```
  - Создаем сам обработчик, в котором проверяем тип объекта и если есть новые объекты, то делаем колонки:

    ```
    private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj is GridView gridView)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.NewValue);
                if (view != null)
                {
                    CreateColumns(gridView, view);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ```
  - Ну и простой метод генерации колонок:

    ```
    private static void CreateColumns(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
    {
        foreach (var item in view)
        {
            GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = "Привет мир!"
            };
            gridView.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }
    ```

  Привязываем все, запускаем и видим, что у нас создалась успешно тестовая колонка (в тестовой коллекции у меня 1 объект)

  [image: Result 1]

Отлично, пол дела сделано, остается нам поработать над заголовками и свойствами.

- Создадим вспомогательный метод, который вернет значение свойства:

  ```
  private static T GetPropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
  {
      if (obj == null) return default;
      PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
      return (T)prop?.GetValue(obj, null);
  }
  ```
- Дальше для удобства вынесем генерацию одной колонки в отдельный метод.
  В этом методе мы берем из свойств `DisplayMember` и `Header` их значения и если они не пустые, то присваиваем их:

  ```
  private static GridViewColumn CreateColumn(GridView gridView, object columnSource)
  {
      GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
      string header = GetHeader(gridView);
      string displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMember(gridView);

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
          column.Header = GetPropertyValue<string>(columnSource, header);

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMemberMember))
      {
          string propertyName = GetPropertyValue<string>(columnSource, displayMemberMember);
          column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyName);
      }
      return column;
  }
  ```
- Перепишем создание колонки в методе `CreateColumns`:

  ```
  GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, item);
  ```

Все, вот базовый пример подобной реализации, давайте испытаем:

- Создаем тестовые данные:

  ```
  class Person
  {
      public Person(string name, int age)
          => (Name, Age) = (name, age);

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
  }

  class Column
  {
      public Column(string header, string displayMember)
          => (Header, DisplayMember) = (header, displayMember);

      public string Header { get; }
      public string DisplayMember { get; }
  }

  class MainViewModel
  {
      public ObservableCollection<Column> Columns { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Column>
      {
          new Column("Имя", "Name")
      };

      public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>
      {
          new Person("Вася", 12),
          new Person("Петя", 19)
      };
  }
  ```
- Привязываем все в XAML:

  ```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
      <ListView.View>
          <GridView
              local:GridViewColumns.DisplayMember="DisplayMember"
              local:GridViewColumns.Header="Header"
              local:GridViewColumns.Source="{Binding Columns}" />
      </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
  ```

  Здесь `DisplayMember` и `Header` - имена соответствующих свойств из класса `Column`, а `Source` - сама коллекция колонок.

И результатом будет одна колонка с именем человека:

[image: Result 2]

Дополним еще пару колонок:

```
public ObservableCollection<Column> Columns { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Column>
{
    new Column("Имя", "Name"),
    new Column("Возраст", "Age"),
    new Column("Неизвестная 1", null),
    new Column("Неизвестная 2", null)
};
```

Результат:

[image: Result 3]

Как видим, все успешно отработало. Я за основу взял [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2644202/6808809), в нем есть ряд вещей, которые я не стал переносить сюда, ибо моей задачей было показать базовый принцип, а дальнейшее развитие этого я оставляю на вас.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. С полями, у которых простое значение, работает.
Но у меня еще было поле "Подчиняется", оно содержало Имя + Фамилия + Id начальника сотрудника. Во ViewModel было свойство с типом ReportsToNav, хранящее объект начальника, и когда колонки описывались вручную, у колонки "Подчиняется" был задан CellTemplate="{StaticResource BossColumnTemplate}", а в нем, соответственно, был шаблон с биндингами к ReportsToNav.LastName, .FirstName, .EmployeeId. Возможно такое сделать и в новом решении?

Comment: @pinkertem Если это ресурс, то его место в ресурсах. Попробуйте установить `DataTemplate` в XAML например, указав тип `ReportsToNav` и нужный для него шаблон. В теории должен автоматом подменить вид.