# DataView из DataTable с меньшим кол-во колонок

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

В общем, есть DataView, который строится на основании DataTable, которую я привязываю к DataGrid.

DataTable используется, так как содержимое заранее неизвестно.

Все работает отлично, но хотелось отображать не все колонки в DataGrid.

Скажем, хочу иметь кнопку с командой при нажатии на которой остается только одна колонка, которую пользователь указал в настройках.

В DataView не нашел способа уменьшить кол-во колонок. Есть вариант клонировать таблицу, удалить из нее колонки, а затем сделать View, но мне не хочется отслеживать изменения в 2-ух DataTable, для последующих операций обновления.

Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Интересный вопрос... я правильно пониаю, что у вас в коде нет класса, поля которого соответствуют колонкам таблицы? я спрашиваю потому, что для таких объектов, кажется, есть решение, основанное на атрибутах полей такого класса

Comment: @S.H. Нету, так как данные динамические.

Comment: [Оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093636/220553).

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то у Вас есть DataGrid контрол, и если это так, то почему нельзя скрыть столбцы в контроле?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Что-то у меня не работает=(( У меня данные не сразу подгружаются в грид, а при нажатии на кнопку. Я в SourceChanged вашего решения попадаю один раз и в первое попадание obj =null и я вылетаю=(

Comment: Точнее вот так https://prnt.sc/1180lgk

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня почему-то при изменении колонок, новые колонки не появляются=( Что можете подсказать?

Comment: В биндингах указан TwoWay.

Comment: Работает только в том случае, если присваивать новый List, а с Observable что-то нет...

Comment: @iluxa1810 Ну так событие изменение DependencyProperty не следит за элементами внутри коллекции, он, по сути, и знать не знает, что там коллекция. Тут нужно при вызове этого события, определять, является ли `e.NewValue` той самой коллекцией (или можно уйти в абстракцию, использовав `INotifyCollectionChanged`), если да, то подписываться на его событие `CollectionChanged`, которое уже в свою очередь и будет отвечать за генерацию колонок. Мельком пробежался по гуглу, нашел [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4362366/6808809), вот +- такое вам надо сделать. Отписываться от события не забывайте!

Answer (score 0):

На основании [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093636/220553), я сделал вот такое решение для себя:

```
public static class DataGridColumns
    {
        public static object GetSource(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(SourceProperty);
        public static void SetSource(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(object), typeof(DataGridColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(default, SourceChanged));

        public static string GetHeader(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        public static void SetHeader(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Header", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(default));

        public static string GetDisplayMember(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberProperty);
        public static void SetDisplayMember(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberProperty, value);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMember", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(default));

        private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (obj is DataGrid gridView)
            {
                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.NewValue);
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        CreateColumns(gridView, view);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private static void CreateColumns(DataGrid dataGrid, ICollectionView view)
        {
            foreach (var item in view)
            {
                var column = CreateColumn(dataGrid, item);
                dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }
        private static T GetPropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
         
            if (obj == null) return default;
            PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            return (T)prop?.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        private static DataGridTextColumn CreateColumn(DataGrid gridView, object columnSource)
        {
            var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            string header = GetHeader(gridView);
            string displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMember(gridView);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
                column.Header = GetPropertyValue<string>(columnSource, header);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMemberMember))
            {
                string propertyName = GetPropertyValue<string>(columnSource, displayMemberMember);
                column.Binding = new Binding(propertyName);
            }
            return column;
        }

    }
```