# C# WPF Создать сложную таблицу посещаемости

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, datagrid

Мне необходимо реализовать таблицу посещаемости.

[image: Вот так примерно.]

У меня есть таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю как это сделать. Пробовала через код добавлять, но столкнулась с проблемой что у меня неопределённое количество столбцов, а чтобы добавить строки надо знать столбцы.

Comment: Используйте посредника DataTable

Comment: Динамичные столбцы можно сделать примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093636/220553), на основе этого примера думаю можно сделать и то, что вы хотите.