# Привязка свойств к DataGridTextColumn.Header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Хотел попробовать привязать какое-нибудь свойство к заголовку столбца DataGrid'а. Перерыл пару источников, но все равно не получилось нормально отобразить данные... Пример кода ниже:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.ColumnTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Поправка: Данный код XAML работает при присваивании DataContext к тому классу, в котором у меня имеется нужное мне свойство. Но у меня на странице находится три вкладки TabItem, на которых есть ListView и нужный мне DataGrid, но в случае изменения DataContext данные в ListView исчезают. Как можно было бы обойти данную ситуацию?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**:
У меня имеется страница, на которой размещен DataGrid для вывода успеваемости студентов.
В состав DataGrid'а входит:

1. название предмета, которое выводится в заголовок строки;
2. дата, на которую ставится оценка и которая выводится в заголовок столбца (Возможно, можно будет опустить вывод дат в заголовки, но учитывать их при выводе оценок все равно нужно);
3. оценка, которая размещена в ячейке на переплетении предмета и даты;

Примерно выглядеть это должно так (Без среднего балла):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент у меня имеется два массива для заполнения заголовков строк и столбцов, а также коллекция для заполнения оценок.

Код StudentPageViewModel:

```
public class StudentPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int?[] marksCollection = StudentPageModel.GetGrades();
    public int?[] MarksCollection
    {
        get => marksCollection;
        set
        {
            marksCollection = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MarksCollection)));
        }
    }
    private string[] gradesRowHeader = StudentPageModel.GetSubjectsTitles();
    public string[] GradesRowHeader
    {
        get => gradesRowHeader;
        set
        {
            gradesRowHeader = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GradesRowHeader)));
        }
    }
    private string[] gradesColumnHeader = StudentPageModel.GetDates();
    public string[] GradesColumnHeader
    {
        get => gradesColumnHeader;
        set
        {
            gradesColumnHeader = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GradesColumnHeader)));
        }
    }

   
    public StudentPageViewModel()
    { 
    }
```

Код xaml с DataGrid, в который должен производиться вывод данных:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MarksCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.GradesColumnHeader[0]}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="200" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=DataContext.GradesRowHeader[0]}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
```

Код StudentModel:

```
 public class StudentPageModel
 {

    public static int?[] GetGrades()
    {
        using (DbStudents Entity = new DbStudents())
        {
            var Result = Entity.Grades.Where(it => it.StudentId == ClassForData.UserID).Select(it => it.Value).ToArray(); //Отбор данных для получения оценок
            return Result;
        }
    }
    public static string[] GetSubjectsTitles()
    {
        using (DbStudents Entity = new DbStudents())
        {
            var Result = Entity.Grades.Where(it => it.StudentId == ClassForData.UserID).Select(it => it.Subject.Title).Distinct().ToArray(); //Отбор данных для получения названий предметов
            return Result;
        }
    }
    public static string[] GetDates()
    {
        using (DbStudents Entity = new DbStudents())
        {
            var Result = Entity.Grades.Where(it => it.StudentId == ClassForData.UserID).Select(it => it.Date.ToString()).Distinct().ToArray(); //Отбор данных для получения дат оценок
            return Result;
        }
    }
 }
```

Конечный вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нумерации столбцов все выводится корректно, однако есть проблема дублирования оценок из первого столбца во все остальные + мне нужно выводить все столбцы динамически без указания нумерации в XAML.

Comment: `работает при присваивании DataContext к тому классу, в котором у меня имеется нужное мне свойство` - а вы хотели как-то иначе? Чтоб класс, который не имеет нужного свойства вдруг его получил? Вообще, у вас должен быть один DataContext у окна, к некоторому `MainViewModel` классу, который в себе уже содержит свойства для привязки. А сейчас я так понял, у вас белеберда в этом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Нет, иначе вовсе никак не хотел, просто потихоньку изучаю это все, так как мало практического опыта)  С MVVM слегка знаком теоретически, но практики вообще никакой :(

Comment: Я вам не говорю сейчас про MVVM, это стандартные понятия привязок, научитесь ими пользоваться, поймите, как работают, к чему привязывать можно, а к чему нет. Конкретно по вопросу, лично мне он не понятен, я не вижу кода полностью, не вижу, где вы задаете `DataContext`, какой он у вас, есть ли там `ColumnTitle`, ну и не совсем понимаю, что именно вы хотите и что сейчас получаете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Здравствуйте! Задали вопрос с другого аккаунта по данной теме. Могу скинуть Вам сюда ссылку? Ибо так и не разобрались с этой темой...

Comment: Вместо того, чтоб спрашивать "можно или нет", лучше сразу скинули бы то, что надо, а лучше, отредактировали бы вопрос так, чтоб он содержал в себе нужную информацию, ваши попытки и т.д. А не так, что где-то есть дубликат вопроса, да еще и с твин. аккаунта...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Отредактировал вопрос.  
P.S. Дубликат был задан с аккаунта человека, с которым вместе делаем проект)

Comment: Видел я [тот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1344164/220553) вопрос, да. Писать что-либо там не стал по одной простой причине - это весьма геморная задача, которая сводится, по сути, к написанию своего контрола. Сейчас вы не совсем то делаете, ибо по стандарту, 1 столбец = 1 ячейка, то есть вы не можете отвязать вот так вот отдельно столбцы, указав им другой массив. Изначально ваш вопрос заключался в том, что вы хотите привязать их к одному некому значению за пределами контрола, ок, это можно, но не к массиву.

Comment: И тут как бы у вас несколько вариантов: 1. По сути, у вас идет группирование по некому значению (дата?), в WPF из коробки есть отличный инструмент [создания групп])(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control), но, опять же, вы не получите так нужный вид без переписывания стилей, контрола и прочего. 2. Вы можете попробовать довести текущий вариант до некого рабочего, но скорей всего придется делать нечто [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093636/220553), и опять же, стили, я не знаю как сделать то, что на скрине

Comment: Ну и 3. Использовать `ItemsControl` или нечто аналогичное, с простым выводом элементов с нужным стилем, имитируя тем самым таблицу. К примеру, [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366486/6808809), получите [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPCI3.png) вид, ну и как видите, может быть любая вложенность групп, любой стиль и так далее. Можете на основе этого уже сделать примерно то, что на скрине, можно даже "группу" оставить в виде простой полосы, а "внутренности", поместить туда `DataGrid` с выводом колонок. Но тут конечно не оч хорошая структура данных получается, хотя...)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Здравствуйте! Попробовал сделать вот [этим](https://clck.ru/Yxmyx) способом. По сути, динамическое создание столбцов реализовано и работает хорошо, однако не могу понять, возможно ли сделать шаблон для вывода конкретных значений под каждый столбец, что я создаю...

Comment: Эм `для вывода конкретных значений под каждый столбец` - а в том вопросе как? На сколько я помню там привязка к любому значению класса для любого столбца.