# C# WPF Как переписать xaml код в code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть коллекция колонок, которая задается в xaml

```
<GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="ColumnCollection">
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="test"  Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DataColumns[0].Value}">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Name="One" Style="{StaticResource style}" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click_1" SizeChanged="GridViewColumnHeader_SizeChanged_1">
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource style}" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DataColumns[0].Value}">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Name="Two" Style="{StaticResource style}" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click_1" SizeChanged="GridViewColumnHeader_SizeChanged_1">
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource style}" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DataColumns[0].Value}">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Name="Three" Style="{StaticResource style}" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click_1" SizeChanged="GridViewColumnHeader_SizeChanged_1">
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <!--<GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource style}" Width="100" Header="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Header}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DataColumns[1].Value}" />-->
        </GridViewColumnCollection>
```

Есть следующий шаблон для отображения этих колонок в Header

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiColumnHeaderTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Columns="{StaticResource ColumnCollection}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Создается DataGrid с колонкой, куда мы указываем наш HeaderTemplate

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"  SizeChanged="GridViewColumnHeader_SizeChanged" Name="datagrid">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="col" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MultiColumnHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MultiColumnCellTemplate}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Как сделать тоже самое, но через CodeBehind? Колонки будут создаваться динамически. Понятия не имею как создать колонку, применить стиль Header в которой будут совсем другая коллекция колонок.

Comment: В WPF не должно быть создание UI через код, забудьте просто про это, считайте такой подход сразу плохим. Советую хотяб базово понять MVVM подход, там очень классно все делится на слои, а именно Model - это всякие файлы, база, работа с сайтом и т.д. View - это весь UI с XAML разметкой и прочим, ну а ViewModel - связующий слой, который берет данные из Model и создает свойства для привязки, которые использует View. Вот вы должны стараться делать так, чтобы View был максимально отвязан от других слоев, для этого в WPF есть механизм привязок.

Comment: Другими словами, вы не должны использовать контролы, как хранилище данных, привяжите их к простым классам и дайте свободу, пусть сами разбираются что и когда создавать. Ну а касательно колонок, то я уже отвечал на такое [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093636/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я знаю что такое MVVM и как с ним работать. Создание колонок будет происходить в самом контроле, а данные будут биндиться. У меня сейчас проблема в том, чтобы сделать внутри колонки DataGrid другие колонки. Так вот стиль хедера в xaml принимает ресурс columncollection. Но не создавать же мне для каждой колонки свой ресурс