# В приложение с использованием Entity Framework необходимо программно добавить столбец в базу данных

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, entity-framework, ado.net

Сразу скажу что прекрасно понимаю что суть моего вопроса в целом противоречит концепции использования базы данных и я знаю что мой визуальный интрефейс должен определятся моей базой и контекстом, а не наоборот. Но в университете мне дали задание написать приложение в котором будет представлен визуальный интерфейс(я решил остановится на WPF потому что в вебе почти ничего не знаю, но если кто то сможет предложить решение для веба буду благодарен) и база данных ( я решил использовать EF для работы с бд потому что база данных достаточно большая и писать кучу sql скриптов с использование Ado.net нет никакого желания, однако опять же если есть решение с использованием этой технологии буду благодарен). Так вот будет визуальный интерфейс и база данных с кучей функционала высшей точкой бреда которого требуется предоставить пользователю возможность самому через UI добавить и удалять колонку из базу данных и заполнять ее, то есть есть условный DataGrid в котором представлены наши начальные данные с базы, по нажатию на кнопку требуется ввести тип и имя новой колонки и она добавляется в базу и UI и через сам UI должна быть возможность ее заполнить. Я готов рассмотреть любые костыли если кто то знает как можно это релизовать, хотя бы чтоб это работало в текущей сессии, тоесть по нажатию на кнопку колонка добавилась в UI ее заполнили, а при перезапуске приложения эта колонка просто томится где то в недрах самой бд и пользователь о ней не узнает. Прошу не ставить негативные отзывы без комментариев ибо я и сам понимаю что вопрос жутко бредовый, но сам придумать такие костыли я не в состоянии

Comment: Ну UI часть довольно [проста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093636/220553), правда с "динамикой" придется повозиться. Ну а вот база... EF тут мне кажется не в тему, ибо он завязан на классах, где вы должны всю базу описать конкретным набором классов, после чего сам EF создает запросы на их основе (включая миграции), ну а так, как у вас простым классом не описать вашу таблицу, скорей всего придется писать SQL запросы вручную, без EF, занося эти данные куда надо, вручную.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,Я в изначально и думал что придется писать SQL, но потом один человек принес жутко костыльную, но рабочую версию на пайтоне с использованием jango orm, я в нём не силен поэтому не понял почти ничего (из того что понял там есть некий метод который возвращает все поля всех классов которые использует orm и туда можно через отдельные скрипты в ручную внести дополнительное поле, думал может аналог какой и шарпе найдется), но работает она как я и писал один раз за сессию, тоесть добавил колонку, заполнил, закрыл приложение, колонка осталась висеть где то в базе.

Comment: По моему решение лежит в другой плоскости. Скорей всего через EF надо создать таблицу AdditionalColumns, где будут лежать типы дополнительных колонок и AdditionalColumnsValues, где будут лежать значения и эта таблица будет относиться 1:n к основной. Добавление колонок будет сводиться к добавлению строчки в AdditionalColumns, а ввод значения будет сводится к добавлению строчки в AdditionalColumnsValues. Останется только решить с фронтом, как вывести доп-колонки в 1 строчку

Comment: На мой взгляд, использование EF не запрещает использовать "чистый" SQL для управления БД, но (как уже было сказано выше) что Вы в таком случае будете декларировать в классах сущностей?

Comment: Тут сам собой напрашивается старый добрый [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0). В него можно добавлять колонки, что автору и нужно. [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) берёт на себя вопросы CRUD.

Comment: Но если непременно надо Entity Framework, то, как уже сказали, посмотрите на [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). EF тоже может с ней работать: [Designing an Entity-Attribute-Value model with Entity Framework Core](https://ekobit.com/blog/designing-an-entity-attribute-value-model-with-entity-framework-core/)